# How to create dropdown menu onchange on another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Can anyone give me demo on how to create dropdown dynamically onchange on another dropdown

I have one dropdown menu in which one can select multiple option like this

```
  <select id='first' multiple='multiple'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>
      <option value='7'>7</option>
      <option value='8'>8</option>
  </select>
```

suppose if user selected first three option from above 1,2 and 3,
I am interested to create one more dropdown with single selection like this in one division

```
<div id='above_selected'>
    <select id='first_selected'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As and when there is a change on `id='first'` I would like to reflect it on another division

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#first').change(function () {
    $('#above_selected').html("<select id='first_selected'></select>");
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val().length; i++) {
        $('#first_selected').append('<option value="' + $(this).val()[i] + '">' + $(this).val()[i] + '</option>');
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U9eUk/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U9eUk/1/ i added the multiple attribute to the appended select.

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this is <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc3p5/1/)**</kbd>

#### jQUery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdown1 = {
        1 : ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'],
        2 : ['Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'],
        3 : ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve'],
        4 : ['Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen'],
        5 : ['Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen']            
    }
    $('#first_selected').html(
            '<option>'+dropdown1[1].join('</option><option>')+'</option>'
        );
    $('#first').on('change',function() {
        $('#first_selected').html(
            '<option>'+dropdown1[$(this).val()].join('</option><option>')+'</option>'
        );
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<select id="first">
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
<select id="first_selected">
```

I think this way is helpful for you to create JavaScript array base on selection array item bind to the another drop down list. Hope this help you!

Comment: i recommended to bind dropdown value from javascript array value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/tLj5z/1/

You will need to update this for your own purposes, but this should give you an idea of where to start.

```
$('#first').change(function(){
       var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        $("#first_selected").append(selected);
});

$('#first_selected').change(function(){
       var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        $("#first").append(selected);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

Add `<div class="add"></div>` and then do the below

```
 $('#first').change(function () {
    if (Number($(this).val()) < 4) {
       $('div.add').html("<div id='above_selected'>    <select id='first_selected'>      <option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option>      <option value='3'>3</option></select></div>");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/6KfBk/1